# Error: ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm creating tables in SQLPLUS

```
ICECREAM (Ice_cream_ID, Ice_cream_flavor, price, years_first_offered, selling _status)
```

which is referencing:

```
INGREDIENT (Ingredient_ID, Ingredient_name, cost)
```

which in turns is referencing this table:

```
CREATE TABLE RECIPE 
(
    Ice_cream_ID CHAR(10) REFERENCES ICECREAM, 
    ingredient_ID CHAR(10) REFERENCES INGREDIENT,
    quantity_used CHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (ice_cream_ID, ingredient_ID)
);
```

I get an error on line 2:

> ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

Do I need FK?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems pretty clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it keeps saying there is an error at line 2, I can't spot the error

Comment: What are the data types of the columns in each table? It looks like you've defined `ice_cream_id` and/or `ingredient_id` differently in the other tables.

Comment: Please share table definition with data type for icecream and ingredient.

Comment: Oh I seeCREATE TABLE RECIPE (
Ice_cream_ID NUMBER(5) references ICECREAM(ice_cream_id), 
ingredient_ID NUMBER(5),
quantity_used FLOAT,
PRIMARY KEY (Ice_cream_ID, ingredient_ID)); --- @AlexPoole

Comment: OK - so you can see than `NUMBER(5)` is not compatible with `VARCHAR2(10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatype might not matching between `Ice_cream_ID` of `icecream` table and `Ice_cream_ID` of `recipe` table or `ingredient_ID` of `ingredient` table and `ingredient_ID` of `recipe` table.

Please check.